# Apache Sqoop-1 reducer phase

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, sqoop

I have gone through the sqoop documentation and did not find the information on why sqoop-1 does not have reducer phase. Can someone please explain this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The purpose of the Reducer is to aggregate the input values and return a single output value.

Look at the simple example of WordCount in MapReduce. The Reducer is used to aggregate the number of occurrences of a single word.

Since the nature of a Sqoop job is to fetch the input records from the given RDBMS and put the records into the given output directory in HDFS or into a Hive table, the job does not require any aggregation and therefore no Reduce phase is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce phase is not needed when all tasks can be executed in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop does not need reducer because it imports/exports data between RDBMS and HDFS file system (or Hive tables.).

since RDBMS consists of structured data there is not need shuffle or sort and aggregation can be done in mapper it self.